# PHP CLI in Windows 7 looking for old xdebug extension after upgrade

Tags: windows, command-line, php

I recently upgraded my PHP version on Windows 7 from 5.5.something to 5.6.25, and at the same time I upgraded my xdebug from 2.3.1-5.5 to 2.4.1-5.6.  I followed the instructions provided by the xdebug wizard, putting the new xdebug .dll file in place of the old one, and editing my php.ini file to point to the new version.

Here are all the lines from my php.ini that contain "xdebug" (all commands entered below in Git Bash):

```
$ grep xdebug "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini"
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

However, when I run any php CLI command at all, I get the following error output:

> Failed loading C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.1-5.5-vc11.dll

PHP is definitely reading the right ini file:

```
$ php --ini
Failed loading C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.1-5.5-vc11.dll
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

And Apache is loading the new xdebug just fine:
[image: phpinfo output showing xdebug loaded]

but the CLI doesn't find it:

```
$ php -i | grep -c xdebug
Failed loading C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.1-5.5-vc11.dll
0
```

Can anyone suggest why the PHP CLI might still be looking for the old version of xdebug, and how I can fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I haven't solved the problem but I worked around it by creating a symlink to the new dll file using the old name.